# How do I fetch value of a dynamically generated checkboxes in an array

Tags: javascript, checkbox, dynamic-arrays

Below is the code to create dynamic checkboxes based on groupcode list that we'll get from seeup service which all is working fine.

But, whenever I am trying to fetch the value of selected only checkboxes in JS onclick function then I am getting value of only the first checkbox which is getting created in the below loop.

```
<ui:grid>
    <xsl:for-each select="seeup:seeup[seeup:groupCode=$groupCode][position() mod 3 = 0 ]">
        <xsl:variable name = "current-pos" select="(position() - 1) * 3+1" />
            <ui:row>
                <xsl:for-each select="../seeup:seeup[seeup:groupCode=$groupCode][position() &gt;= $current-pos and position() &lt; $current-pos + 3]" >
                    <ui:cell class="ap-apply-fieldName-grid">
                        <ui:checkBox name="fieldName">
                            <xsl:attribute name="class">
                                ap-apply-fieldName-chkBox
                            </xsl:attribute>
                            <xsl:attribute name="value">
                                <xsl:value-of select="seeup:itemCode"/>
                            </xsl:attribute>
                        </ui:checkBox>
                        <xsl:sequence select="seeup:defaultLabel"/>
                    </ui:cell>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </ui:row>
    </xsl:for-each>
</ui:grid>
```

Comment: If you're generating it with XSL and getting it with Javascript then how does Java figure into this question?

Comment: why this question is tagged in java?